# How can I get average of the numbers from Column A in Column B with one formula which I can drag through the end in Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Here is the following table: So far I have tried:

```
=Average(OFFSET($A2,0,COUNT($A2:$A5642)-1,1,0))
```

but I am not

[image]

Comment: What version of Excel do you have?

Answer (score 1):

In`B2` use: `=IFERROR(AVERAGE(INDEX(A:A,MAX(ROW($A$1:A1)*($A$1:A1=""))+1):A1)/(A2=""),"")`

Enter with `ctrl+shift+enter` in Excel versions prior to Office 365.

Answer (score 1):

If you have Excel 365, you can use Xmatch or Xlookup to do a reverse search, e.g.

```
=IF(OR(B1<>"",A2<>""),"",AVERAGE(A2:XLOOKUP(TRUE,A$1:A1="",A$1:A1,A$1,0,-1)))
```

[image]

If you wanted to be fancy, a spill formula using Scan:

```
=LET(range1,A1:A18,range2,A2:A19,
total,SCAN(0,range1,LAMBDA(a,b,IF(ISNUMBER(b),a+b,0))),
count,SCAN(0,range1,LAMBDA(a,b,IF(ISNUMBER(b),a+1,0))),
IFERROR(IF(range2="",total/count,""),""))
```

Comment: Good use of XLOOKUP. I didn't think of it's reverse lookup capability which comes in handy in cases like this.

Answer (score 0):

Doing things step by step makes it a lot easier (and clearer for anybody else in the future)

Add a column (let's say C) which has:
in C2: `=if(a2='',0,1)`
And D
in D2: `1`
in D3: `=if(a3='',d2+1,d2)` and drag it down

Now you have some choices.
I would do a Pivot Table:
In C1 put `Inclusion`, in D1 put `Group`;
In the Pivot table:
Report Filter: Inclusion (=1)
Row labels: Group
Values: Purchase Values (and select Average)

Alternatively:
in E1 put `Item`, E2 put 1, E3 `=IF(A3="",0,E2+1)` and copy down
in F1 put `Running`, F2 put `=A2`, F3 put `=IF(A2=0,A3,F2+A3)`
in G1 put `Average`, G2 put `=IF(E3=0,IF(E2=0,"_",F2/E2),"_")`